# java - Is this technique for handling client/server hashed password OK?

Tags: java, validation, encryption

Reading alot about how to handle the HASH SALT+password the right way
and I came up with this. what do you think about this scenario:

When a new user is first registering.

- client enter name/pass locally and it's sent with Public Key RSA encryption to server.
- server validate user/pass and if decision is granted an HASH SALT+pass version is sent back.
- the private SALT is stored on server.

Now when user continuously logging he use the above client-side-stored SALTED password and if a hacker want the password he need to hack the server for the SALT right? All continuous logging with this HASH SALT+password are also Public Key RSA encrypted.

Im no expert in crypto but know one can use two ways public/private key encryption and other more advanced ways. This are a bit above my head so that's why i ask this

what is wrong/right with this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to keep the salt private given it will be hashed with the username and password in order to create a unique (session based) hash. Given it's a hash it cannot be reversed (i.e. you cannot derive username, password or salt from the hash). All that is required is to generate the session salt and save it with any other session variables at the server.  The server will then reproduce the hash using the username, password and salt and compare it with the value sent from the client.

This way you don't NEED encryption at all (although it's recommended).  If you don't have a secure website (i.e. using https) then you can still use this technique to protected passwords.

This technique is called [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).

Comment: *"This way you don't NEED encryption at all."* - That's wrong. No matter if the users sends password or hashed password to the server, it must be encrypted.

Comment: @maartinus: encryption is strictly optional.  The client doesn't send a password or a hashed password to the server; it sends a hashed username+password+salt.

Comment: What stops an attacker, eavesdropping on the wire, from sending the same hash? If you'd hash password + message, you'd be safe against attacks other than replays, but I don't see how hashing username along with password and salt helps.

Comment: @gustafc: The server generates the salt each login attempt (i.e. each session) so it's unique.  The server uses the salt saved with it's session variables along with the plaintext username and the password retrieved from the database to recreate the hashed string and compare it with that presented by the client.

Comment: @trojanfoe But what about the first time a new user in my scenario login, he send the user/pass not HASHED but only the Public Key RSA encryption is used.
Server then construct the HASH SALT+PASS and send it back to be user. Next time user login he use the given by server hash-password transfer-protected with the Public Key RSA encryption. Is this ok?

Comment: @EriK:  The login can only happen using a session key (salt) generated  by the server, so you need to get that back to the client before the hashing can start.  The client can then hash username+password+key (using HMAC) and send it back with the plaintext username to allow the server to recreate the hash itself and compare it with that given to it by the client.

Comment: im confused this explanation is hard to understand, HMAC say that Server can identify all clients since Clients have given the Server there unique key. This sounds like i should create a second set of RSA pub/priv keys but now the Client holding the Private Key. My base knowledge is not enough i need more visual explanation. What about breaking down my question above, use that as starting point because that i can understand

Comment: You can simply adapt HMAC to suit your needs; if you want to lock down the which clients can connect to the server then you'd need to deal with private keys at the clients; if you don't you can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

What about this

What about when all Clients that are logging in for the first time,
first hide the plane site password locally by creating a random large SALT applied to the password.
(now the visible password is gone locally right)

They then logon to the server with Public Key RSA encryption and
create a new user account and the server save the above locally created hash password.

Next time the same user login using Public
Key RSA encryption the server will compare hashes right

For an hacker to login he need the hash password with is encryptet with Public Key RSA encryption

any comment?

**UPDATE:**
One problems with this.
 - if the SALT is random there is now way of comparing password if lets say user    uninstall and then reinstall program and want to login again using his old account.
His old account SALT+Password will not be the same. So we need to send USER a SALT
or locally create the salt in a very smart way so hackers cannot see this.

ATE: